# set up ImageView visible depending on a variable

Tags: java, android, variables, imageview

I Programm a Quiz App. How can I set up that if my Highscore is over 10 the ImageView s visible. It works very fine the only Problem that after the app restart the ImageView isn`t visible anymore. How can i set up that over a score of 10, the ImageView is permanently there? The main Code is in Quiz Activity, in Menu2 the ImageView should be visible permanently.

Quiz Activity:

```
package amapps.impossiblequiz;

            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
            import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
            import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
            import android.view.MenuItem;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private MenuItem menuItem;
private Intent in;

private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

private TextView mScoreView;
private TextView mQuestionView;
private Button mButtonChoice1;
private Button mButtonChoice2;
private Button mButtonChoice3;

private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    //Randromize the row of the questions
    QuestionLibrary q = new QuestionLibrary();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    q.shuffle();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));

    //End randomizer

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"


    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_stats):
                    Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu2.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);


        updateQuestion();

        //Start of Button Listener1
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();


                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener1

        //Start of Button Listener2
        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();



                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Oh... wrong your score is 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener2

        //Start of Button Listener3
        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();



                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Come on, that was not so hard...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener3

    }


private void updateQuestion() {

    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}

    private void updateScore ( int point){
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);

    }


    @Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Menu2:

```
package amapps.impossiblequiz;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
        import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import static amapps.impossiblequiz.R.id.nv2;

        public class Menu2 extends AppCompatActivity {




private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout2;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);


     TextView txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore2);
     TextView txtHighScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);
     ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trophy1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int mScore = intent.getIntExtra ("score",0);
    txtScore.setText("Your score is: " + mScore);
    int applyView = 0;

    SharedPreferences mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
    if (highScore>= mScore)
        txtHighScore.setText("High score: " + highScore);


    else{
        txtHighScore.setText("New highscore: " + mScore);
        applyView = mScore;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore",mScore);
        editor.commit();


    }

    if (applyView >10)
        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawerLayout2 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout2);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout2, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout2.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv2);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_home2):
                    Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity2);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });



}




@Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
}
```

Comment: store the score in sharedprefences and when load again the app check if sharedpreference score is more that 10 and if true set view visible to image view else do nothing.

Comment: Ok How can I do that sir?

Comment: just save the current score like you save the highscore and check if corrent score is more that ten.

Comment: Like this one? SharedPreferences mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int varTest= mypref.getInt("You reached rank 1", 10);

Comment: Something like that  mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); int currentscore= mypref.getInt("current_score", 0);

if(currentscore >=10){
     imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

Comment: Could you write me the Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change this:

```
private void updateScore ( int point){
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);

}
```

to this:

```
private void updateScore ( int point){
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);

        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("currentscore", mScore);
        editor.commit();
}
```

And in your Menu2 change this:

```
int applyView = 0;
```

To:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int applyView =sharedpreferences.getInt("currentscore",0);
```

Edit:

Remove this line:

```
applyView = mScore;
```

Comment: I will try this one

Comment: Where do I have to write imgView.setVisibility(View.Visible?)

Comment: just do these changes and see if Works if not i will update the answer with full code.

Comment: in the if is somethig like that if (applyView >10)
        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Thanks man it works but now i have a delay when I press the button retry Quiz... It Needs like 1 second and then i can Remake the quiz before this "update" it went immediately to quizactivity please help me..

Comment: where is button retry quis I dont see the button in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (highScore >10)
        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

when you are testing on `applyView` it could be stay 0 if `highScore>= mScore`

save data like this :

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

private void updateScore ( int point){
    mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    if(mScore > 10){
       Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
       editor.putInt("score", mScore);
       editor.commit();
   }
}
```

Comment: just change applyview with high score as i said

Comment: Nothing appears, with mScore the pic. appears. But if I restart the app  it is invisible

Comment: try to save the new score at the `updateScore` method

Comment: Another one told me I should save up the mScore if it is >10, and then set up the visibility of the imgView how about that?

Comment: but you are noting saving the data anywhere

Comment: change your get preference when reading by `getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: I will try it later Sir.. any other suggestions?

Comment: that's all for now i think it will makes everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

In the If clause:

```
if (highScore >= mScore)
```

you don't change the value of `applyView`. So when the preference value has been saved the first time around and the app is relaunched the If clause is satisfied, so `applyView` is always equal to 0. Meaning that

```
if (applyView >10)
```

is never satisfied at this point.

Comment: You need ```applyView = mScore;``` inside of the if clause (or move both outside of the statement so you only need to set it once)

Comment: That will not work,because everytime mScore is <10 the ImageView won`t Display.I want that if one time the score is over ten the Image will be displayed ever since then

Comment: So regardless of the current mScore you want to show it if it's reached 10 at some point in time? If you want that, then you'll need to save another flag in preferences to mark that the score has reached at least 10 at some point in time, such as PREF_FLAG_HAS_REACH_MINIMUM_SCORE - save true in preferences when the score reaches 10 and use that onwards.